# Передать данные в input при нажатии кнопки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, есть ф-ция, как мне сделать так, что при нажатии на кнопку в несколько инпутов передавались данные из массива (саму функцию передачи никак не могу додумать)

```
    function getmesseg14(){
container.innerHTML = '<input class="ok" type="button" value="OK" onclick="getmesseg56(); return false">';
function getmesseg56(){
``var mynewvar = [  {vaal1:value="12",vaal2:'10.5',vaal3:'12',}  ];
};};
```

Comment: Подробнее объясните, совершенно не понял что вы хотите сделать..

Comment: Пожалуйста, такие сообщения пишите как комментарий к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, пожалуй начну с того, как грамотно должны быть оформлены методы.

```js
 function getMessage() {
   var messagesArray = ['1st message', '2nd message', '3rd message'];
   $('div#container').empty();

   $(messagesArray).each(function(k) {
     $('div#container').append('<div class="message">' + messagesArray[k] + '</div>');
   });
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="getMessage()">Fetch my array messages</button>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Соблюдайте названия методов, при их создании. Если метод должен создать сообщение, то - createMessage (createMsg), удалить - deleteMessage, изменить - editMessage.

**UPD**

Переписал под jQuery